# App gets assistive access removed when launched

Tags: macos, applescript

I am really new to AppleScript, this is my first script. I'm trying to launch GeoGuessr trough an app and changing the user agent to Google Chrome (Because the default one is really buggy on it)

Here is my code

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
tell application "Safari"
    tell front window
        set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:"https://geoguessr.com"})
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Safari"
        click menu item "Google Chrome — MacOS" of menu "User Agent" of menu item "User Agent" of menu "Develop" of menu bar item "Develop" of menu bar 1
    end tell
end tell
```

When I launch it trough script editor, it works and changes the user agent to chrome. But when I run it trough the app itself, it gives me this error.

```
System Events got an error: GeoGuessr is not allowed assistive access. (-1719)
```

Everytime I go check the permissions in the settings, the little box next to my app isn't ticked anymore. Why does it do that?

Comment: As I said, I ticked the box. It unticks itself when I open the app tho

Comment: Is that all there is to the application?  Is it code signed?  Note that AppleScript historically saves global properties and variables by modifying the script file, which can change the accessibility.

Comment: I've not done anything else to the code, so I don't think it's signed. How do I check that? That's all there is to the application, I basically copy pasted 2 different scripts and tried to put them together to create what I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go System Preferences --> Security & Privacy --> **Accessibility**.

Your application should be in the list of **apps allowed to control computer**.

Now, exists 2 cases to move further:

a) checkbox of you app is **NOT CHECKED**.
In this case simply check it.

b) checkbox of you app is **CHECKED** (but doesn't work as you say).
In this case remove your app from list, using MINUS button,
relaunch your app, go again step a).